# Show label near product price, depending on product category

Tags: magento, static, block, product

I have these line of code inside view.phtml that works and shows the content of the static block near product price, only for products of categories id specified in the array.

There is a problem. It doesn't work if I click on "Catalogue" or if I get the product page from search results. I cannot add "Catalogue" category id in my array, because I want to show static block only on specific categories.
Can you help me?

```
    <?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();?>
    <?php $arr = array(116, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 126, 128, 129, 130, 132, 133, 136);?>

        <?php if(in_array($category->getId(),$arr)): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('prezzo-metro')->toHtml(); ?> 
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes It will not work when you come from catalog search or if you open product URl directly in browser. Because in that case you will not get the current category id.

You will need to use code as below.

```
<?php
if (Mage::registry('current_category')) {
    $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
} else {
    $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    if (count($categoryIds)) {
        $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[0];
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);
    }
}
?>

<?php $arr = array(116, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 126, 128, 129, 130, 132, 133, 136); ?>

<?php if (in_array($category->getId(), $arr)): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('prezzo-metro')->toHtml(); ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```